# Passing data to queued Mail object in Laravel 4, using Iron.io

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, iron

I am trying to set up a queued email in Laravel 4 using the Iron.io driver. I would like to pass some details to the email's Subject and From attributes but they seem to not be making it into the queue request and their presence causes the email to not be sent (not sure where to look for a log with errors). However, simply using `Mail::Send()` works fine.

Here is the code in question:

```
public function handleFeedbackForm() 
{
    $data = array(
        'name_f' => Input::get('name_f'),
        'name_l' => Input::get('name_l'),
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'commentType' => Input::get('commentType'),
        'testimonialPublish_answer' => Input::get('testimonialPublish_answer'),
        'comment' => Input::get('message')
    );
    $rules = array(
        'name_f' => 'required',
        'name_l' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'
    );

    $v = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($v->passes()) 
    {
        $emailInfo = array('name_f' => Input::get('name_f'), 
                           'name_l' => Input::get('name_l'), 
                            'email' => Input::get('email'));

        Mail::queue('emails.feedback', $data, function($message) use($emailInfo) 
        {
            $recipients = array();
            $form = MailType::find(1);

            foreach ($form->users as $user) 
            {
                $recipients[] = $user->email;
            }

            if (count($recipients) == 0) 
            {
                // Nobody for this field, send to webmaster
                $recipients[] = 'someone@somewhere.com';
            }

            $message->to($recipients)
                ->from($emailInfo['email'])
                ->subject('Foobar Feedback Form Message - ' . $emailInfo['name_f'] . ' ' . $emailInfo['name_l']);
        });

        return Redirect::to('contact')->with('feedbackSuccess', true);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('contact')->with('feedbackError', true);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: are you on localhost or server? Iron.io doesn't work when using localhost

Comment: It is a production server but is fully accessible to the outside world. The queue works if I do not attempt to add the variables to the subject.

Comment: Queueing closures means the variables passed to the closure are serialized. Try dumping `unserialize(serialize($emailInfo))`, see if it looks correct. In general I'd also try to keep the closure as free of logic as possible, because the serialization of closures is what I like to call black magic (and a wonky process) - you can do most of that logic outside of the closure.